# Unable to display variable value in 16x2 LCD with Arduino

Tags: variables, arduino, arduino-ide, lcd

I am trying to get sensor input into my program and display it in a 16x2 LCD Display. I have two proximity sensors where the time difference between the two inputs is calculated and used in a formula. That value is applied to a variable and I want that value to be displayed in the LCD. It works fine with the Serial Monitor, but the values look Gibberish in the LCD.

I have changed the pin from 1 to 2 so that it is now "LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7); ".

And now the sequence runs but no data is shown in the LCD. Maybe it is in loop and hence it is overwriting continuously. Is there a way to change the sequence so that the value comes only once and data shows in the LCD? (i.e, it is continuously providing output and if i try a while loop, it still shows nothing. Serial Monitor also goes empty.

[Serial Monitor Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWeMM.png)

[LCD Display Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkLXX.jpg)

Please find my code below and help me out with this issue.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> 
LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7); 
int limitSwitch = 13;
int limitSwitch2 = 12;
int state1 = LOW;
int state2 = LOW;
float centimeter = 0.050;
float timeRequired = 0.000;
float velocity = 0.000;
float durationFloat = 0.000;
unsigned long startTime;
unsigned long endTime;
unsigned long duration;
byte timerRunning;

void setup() 

              {

              Serial.begin(9600);
              lcd.begin(16,2); 


              pinMode(limitSwitch,INPUT);
              pinMode(limitSwitch2,INPUT);

        }


void loop() 


  {

      int val1 = digitalRead(limitSwitch);
      int val2 = digitalRead(limitSwitch2);

      lcd.clear();

    if( val1 != state1 || val2 != state2 )

    {

   state1 = val1;
   state2 = val2;

    if( state1 == 0 && timerRunning == 0 )
   startTime = millis();
   timerRunning = 1;

    if( state2 == 0 && timerRunning == 1)

    endTime = millis();
    timerRunning = 0;
    duration = endTime - startTime;
    durationFloat = (float) duration;


    timeRequired = durationFloat / 1000;
    velocity = centimeter / timeRequired;

    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Speed: ");
    lcd.print(velocity);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

    Serial.print("Speed in m/s = ");
    Serial.println(velocity,7);

 //   lcd.print("Speed: "); lcd.print(velocity);

    delay(1000);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try an example first to check if the wiring is correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a wiring problem, not programming.

Comment: I have checked with a sample program and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you are using pin 1, but pin 0 and 1 in arduino are dedicated to the serial you are using

Comment: Yes. I have changed it and I put the lcd.print at the beginning of the loop. It is working fine now. Thank you.